# Jest test fails to match partial object

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I would like to assert only on a portion of response payload, specifically I want to check that senderData is empty: `senderData: {}`

index.js

```
dbTransactionlog.write(loggerData, (err, res) => {
  ...
}
```

index.test.js

```
const spyWrite = jest.spyOn(dbTransactionlog, 'write').mockImplementation((loggerData, cb) => cb(null, undefined));

expect(spyWrite).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
        senderData: {}
    })
);
```

Error I get:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: ObjectContaining {"senderData": {}}
Received: {"deliveryStatus": "failure", "email": "MFLUKVL5BN5L", "payload": {"constructor": {}, "country": "US", "emailReferenceId": "67890", "emailScheduledTime1": "03-12-2019 15:10:10", "language": "en", "recipient": {"firstName": "alpha", "lastName": "beta"}, "recipientSrc": {"id": "MFLUKVL5BN5L", "name": "oxygen"}, "senderData": {}, "sourceSystem": "AUM Messenger", "templateData": {"X-ADSK-MB-REF-ID": "67890", "X-ADSK-RETENTION-TYPE": "financial", "country": "US", "email": "sai.krishna.praveen.kota@autodesk.com", "featuresAdded": ["Autodesk Character Generator"], "firstName": "Sai", "language": "en", "lastName": "Kota", "offeringName": "Architecture Engineering Construction Collection", "recipientData": {}}, "templateId": "12345"}, "provider": undefined, "providerTemplateId": undefined, "source": "AUM Messenger", "templateId": "12345", "ttl": "1625768608"}, [Function anonymous]

Number of calls: 1
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yep. This is because `senderData` is enclosed inside `payload`: `expect.objectContaining({ payload: expect.objectContaining({ senderData: {} }) })`

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov that didn't work :(
`
Expected: ObjectContaining {"payload": ObjectContaining {"senderData": {}}}
Received: {"deliveryStatus": "failure", "email": "MFLUKVL5BN5L", "payload": {"constructor": {}, "country": "US", "emailReferenceId": "67890", "emailScheduledTime1": "03-12-2019 15:10:10", "language": "en", "recipient": {"firstName": "alpha", "lastName": "beta"}, ...
`